# ANT returns build success on Java Run Time errors

Tags: java, ant, build

we run a given task using ANT which creates some configuration files and then run a sw for us.

We are experiencing some run time error inside the virtual machine and it seems ANT is not able to catch it: it simply gives me BUILD_SUCCESS.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the task in question; at a first glance it means the program which creates these configuration files is misbehaving

Comment: "run time error" is ambiguous. What exact error happens? What is the Ant code that causes the error?

Comment: Add debug="true" in <javac > tag as a attribute

Comment: We get a heap corruption error, but it is not relevant I guess. Ant works perfectly, the sw that is called misbehaves it gives rise to the mentioned heap corruption error and ant returns a successful result. Which is not correct.

Comment: Then fix the software... You have no choice here

Comment: I know that I have to fix the sw, this is really non informative, but thanks anyway for remarking it. So, you mean that there is no way to recognize that a sw called in a target caused an issue like that and then report the failure?

Comment: If using ant builtin java task you have to set failonerrror="true" (default is failonerror="false") to make ant fail if error occurs. If using a selfwritten task, it has to throw a BuildException to make ant exit with BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant can only check the exit code of a Java process it launches. If the exit code is zero, then it will dispaly BUILD_SUCCESS, otherwise it will display a build failure.  Therefore, you software needs to call `System.exit(1)` (or any non-zero value) at some point, for Ant to be aware that it was not successful.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I do think this explains my problem. We are on it.

Comment: Beside that ant java task must also set failonerrror="true" (default is failonerror="false") to make ant fail in case of exit code != 0